# How can I delete 360 photos from Google My Business?

Tags: google-my-business

The title says it all really. Deleting regular photos is not a problem (just click on the photo in question and then the trash can in the top right corner).

The same cannot be said for 360 photos. There is no trash can once you click into it and I'm unable to find any photo management options.